# How to render a complete html page received as response in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch, httpresponse

In my React app I have a GET `fetch` to API, which sends me a whole html page as string in response (with `DOCTYPE` declaration and everything). It works as intended when I just type the URL in browser.

Is there a way in React to render it?

Comment: Why is the API returning an entire HTML document in the first place? Why are you not just linking to it if it returns an entire HTML document?

Comment: It's a keycloak login. Shit, I must've been coding too much today :) Thanks for response though.